# Best response to the Evolution of Trust? - Part 1

Tags: code-golf, game

### Backstory

I was fiddling around with the [Evolution of Trust](https://ncase.me/trust) and thought of this.
**Warning**: I recommend you go [check it out first](https://ncase.me/trust) before attempting this challenge.

### Summary for people who haven’t played

A quick summary of what it says [on the site](https://ncase.me/trust): there is a machine. If you put in one coin, your **opponent** gets **three** coins (and vice versa). You can either Cooperate (put in a coin) or Cheat (don't put in a coin).

### Challenge

Given the name of a strategy (`copycat`, `alwayscheat`, `alwayscooperate`, `grudger` or `detective`) and the number of rounds, return/output a list of truthy (Cooperate) and falsey (Cheat) values that, when put against that strategy, will give you the maximum possible amount of coins. (I'm using Y for cooperate and N for cheat in my examples)

For clarification, check the **Input and Output** section.

### Quick info for people who have played

The amount of rounds is given in the input. There are no mistakes, and the rewards for Cooperating/Cheating are the same as [the site](https://ncase.me/trust) - see the image below.

[image: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyEIQ.jpg]

<sub>Yes, this is basically a Prisoner's Dilemma - [Nicky Case](http://ncase.me/) says this in the “[feetnotes](https://ncase.me/trust/notes/)” of the game.
Also, "Cheat" is basically the same as Defect.</sub>

### The characters

- Copycat `copycat`
- Always Cooperate `alwayscooperate`
- Always Cheat `alwayscheat`
- Grudger `grudger`
- Detective `detective`

### The characters' strategies from [the site](https://ncase.me/trust)

- Copycat: Hello! I start with Cooperate, and afterwards, I just copy whatever you did in the last round. *Meow*
- Always Cheat: *the strong shall eat the weak* (always cheats)
- Always Cooperate: Let's be best friends! <3 (always cooperates)
- Grudger: Listen, pardner. I'll start cooperatin', and keep cooperatin', but if y'all ever cheat me, **I'LL CHEAT YOU BACK 'TIL THE END OF TARNATION.** (cooperates until you cheat once, then cheats you back for the rest of the game)
- Detective: First: I analyze you. I start: Cooperate, Cheat, Cooperate, Cooperate. If you cheat back, I'll act like Copycat. If you never cheat back, I'll act like Always Cheat, to exploit you. Elementary, my dear Watson.

### Input and Output

Input is the name of the strategy and the amount of rounds in any order you specify, in a list, or a space-separated string.

Output is a list of truthy (Cooperate) and falsey (Cheat) values that, when put against the strategy, gives you the most amount of points.

### Test cases

```
"grudger 3" => "YYN" or [<2 truthy values>, falsey]
"detective 5" => "NNNYN" or [<3 falsey values,> truthy, falsey]
"alwayscheat 7" => "NNNNNNN" or [<7 falsey values>]
"alwayscooperate 99" => <insert 99 N's here> or [<99 falsey values>]
"copycat 7" => "YYYYYYN" or [<6 truthy values>, falsey]
"detective 4" => "NNNN" (4 N's) or [<4 falsey values>]
"alwayscheat 999" => 999 N's or [<999 falsey values>]
"grudger 1" => "N" or [falsey]
```

Easy copy paste:

```
grudger 3
detective 5
alwayscheat 7
alwayscooperate 99
copycat 7
detective 4
alwayscheat 999
grudger 1
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins, tiebreaks sorted by time(stamp) created
- Standard loopholes are not allowed, unless they are creative (e.g. asking for list input and using the fact that it is a *list* to shorten your code). No extra points are given for this

> WD

Comment: Is shorter detective allowed as input?

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify.

Comment: For reference, [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1590/58563) is our current consensus about answering your own challenge.

Comment: This will be a nice KotH challenge.

Comment: @l4m2 I haven’t heard from you for a while, so I’ll leave `detective` as it is now. @Arnauld got it, thanks. @wasif Good idea, I’ll add it to the sandbox some day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>An OP accepted, but somewhat rule-bending, 13 byter since all the integers are now wrapped in lists - so it only works if we may assume any truthy/falsey operator will vectorise - that can be fixed for 1 byte for a different 14 to my original, e.g. add `F`.)</sup>

```
M_5+Ṡ$×<¥ⱮḊ;0
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the opponent classification on the left and the number of turns to play on the right and yields a list of wrapped integers (non-zeros are truthy in Jelly, while zeros are falsey).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//TV81K@G5oCTDlzzCpeKxruG4ijsw////J2RldGVjdGl2ZSf/NQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9833lT74c4FKoen2xxa@mjjuoc7uqwN/h9erv@oaU3io4a5kflAwi/rUeM@Lq7//6Oj1dOLSlPSU4vUdRSMY7l0otVTUktSk0syy1KBIqZgkcSc8sTK4uSM1MQSoJg5slh@fkFqUWIJSK2lJVgiOb@gMhlJIbJxJliMs4TqQzjDMJYrFgA).

#### How?

There are, for the purpose of our choices, only three classes of opponent here:

1. If we face `alwayscheat` or `alwayscooperate` we should always cheat
2. If we face `grudger` or `copycat` we should cooperate until our penultimate turn and then cheat on our final turn.
3. If we face `detective` we should cooperate from the fourth turn (if it is not our last turn) until our penultimate turn and then cheat on our final turn.

```
M_5+Ṡ$×<¥ⱮḊ;0 - Link: opponent, turns
M             - maximal indices
                -> alwayscheat:[5] alwayscooperate:[5] grudger:[3] copycat:[4] detective:[8]
                       ^               ^                 ^            ^               ^
 _5           - subtract five
                -> alwayscheat:[0] alwayscooperate:[0] grudger:[-2] copycat:[-1] detective:[3]
   +Ṡ$        - add the sign of that (call this "category")
                -> alwayscheat:[0] alwayscooperate:[0] grudger:[-3] copycat:[-2] detective:[4]
         Ɱ    - map (across turn in [1..turns]) with:
        ¥     -   last two links as a dyad, f(category, turn)
       <      -     (category) less than (turn)?
      ×       -     (category) multipied by (that)
          Ḋ   - dequeue
           ;0 - concatenate a zero
```

---

14: `OḢ%4C×4×<¥ⱮḊ;0`

And another 14: `OḢ%4ȯ7B¤Ṭo¥@’ṁ`

Comment: The 13-byte submission should be fine. +1 for good creativity

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Å0Dā4›Àā¤Ê)ICθè
```

First input is the amount of rounds, second input the strategy of the opponent.
Output is a list of 1s/0s.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX//8OFMETEgTTigLrDgMSBwqTDiilJQ864w6j//zEwCmRldGVjdGl2ZQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2lckJx6P/DrQYuRxpNHjXsOtxwpPHQksNdmhHO53YcXvFf5396UWlKemqRgjFXSmpJanJJZlmqgilXYk55YmVxckZqYomCOYyXn1@QWpRYkqpgacmVnF9QmQyWRGgzQdFmCVQFM9wQAA).

**Explanation:**

There are three different output variations based on the input \$n\$:

- `detective`: \$N(\min(n-1,3))Y(n-4)N(1)\$
- `grudger`/`copycat`: \$Y(n-1)N(1)\$
- `alwayscheat`/`alwayscooperate`: \$N(n)\$

So in my program I create these three possible lists first; convert the string input to an index-integer; and use it to output the correct list of the three.

```python
Å0         # Push a list with the first (implicit) input amount of 0s: [0,0,...,0,0]
D          # Duplicate this list
ā          # Push a list in the range [1, length] (without popping the list)
 4›        # Check for each whether it's larger than 4 (0 if <=4; 1 if >4)
   À       # Rotate it once left: [0,0,0, 1,1,...,1,1, 0]
ā          # Push a list in the range [1, length] (without popping the list)
 ¤         # Get its last value (without popping)
  Ê        # Check for each that it's NOT equal to this integer: [1,1,...,1,1, 0]
    )      # Wrap all four lists on the stack into a list
     I     # Push the input-string
      C    # Convert it from a binary-string to an integer
       θ   # Only leave its final digit
        è  # Use that to 0-based modulair index into the list of lists
           # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)
```

`C` on strings basically gets the index of each characters in the string `` 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzǝʒαβγδεζηθвимнт ΓΔΘιΣΩ≠∊∍∞₁₂₃₄₅₆ !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~Ƶ€Λ‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒĆŽƶĀ‘’“”–—˜™š›œćžŸā¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬λ®¯°±²³\nµ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ• ``, and then converts this list of indices to a base-2 integer.

| String | `C` | `θ` | Modulair index | Resulting list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| detective | 21282 | 2 | 2 | `[0,0,0, 1,1,...,1,1, 0]` |
| grudger | 5893 | 3 | 3 | `[1,1,...,1,1, 0]` |
| copycat | 5607 | 7 | 3 | `[1,1,...,1,1, 0]` |
| alwayscheat | 87191 | 1 | 1 | `[0,0,...,0,0]` |
| alwayscooperate | 1397550 | 0 | 0 | `[0,0,...,0,0]` |

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

Based on OP's answer

```ruby
->a,b{([p]*(~a.ord%4)+[a>?b]*b)[0,b-1]<<p}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoJAFIX38xR3UVQ2SlIRRjlv0D5E4o7eTLBmGMdM@nl1s0Ci5fnOd46pZNMet60bIpf3caRjZ/xCT5l0uJhMIwyFjB05iWZcun682ehnW5/ygiAjWzIA5CBhC4ODV@oitx3RlS1BuM6cd5TDMfoonlWHPPbOqO@P2@MGQuzXYvd0RiNGl7TNTJVmZGDOUrKU2PxKsGRY1NiUyYnQwqpPSmkyaAmCgCVKN8m3/M0Wf7Ogs/pz/w0)

`[p]*(~a.ord%4)` could be `[p]*3*a.sum[2]` or `[p]*(a.hex/74)` instead for the same length.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(hash(a)%5%4*[0]+[a>'b']*b)[:b-1]+[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc2xboNADAbgPU/hJfJBQpW0iSqQ0i0d26VLRRl8YMI1lDuZowlPT0EZiNTJ8qffv13vK9s8DuXha6jpRxcEtNaJqqitFAXL/XIXpptsldILasxCHaSJjrYjbLLhUpma4UM6ThYAXvppADgxjVcYRREGMwDiw7c1jcJPBFPCFbhuGfANobQyrqaBUoWmcZ1XQTBd8jVn5@H4/noUsXJr18J0HlI8SVecWHANT9kixYI959788gj7Cai@UN/mFZMf6fmOrHUs5KdkHE@eW9fnc@y@ave/Kr4dzf@32R8)

| name | `hash(name)` | `hash(name)%5%4` | `name>'b'` | pattern |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| grudger | -2066041371107544871 | 0 | True | `N{0}Y{b-1}N` |
| detective | -4897940859603653632 | 3 | True | `N{3}Y{b-4}N` |
| alwayscheat | 5996996683077751943 | 3 | False | `N{3}N{b-4}N` |
| alwayscooperate | 6213961190923822520 | 0 | False | `N{0}N{b-1}N` |
| copycat | 8335118083446687010 | 0 | True | `N{0}Y{b-1}N` |

Comment: `hash(a)%755%4*[0]` also works, but that's sadly just as long

Comment: @Arnauld but `hash(a)%5%4*[0]` works, because *alwayscheat* continues with `N/0` anyway

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 45 bytes

```
lambda o,r:([len(o)<8]*3+[o>'c']*r)[:r-1]+[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BbsIwDIbP9CksLk6gnai6abQae4TdUcghS1PIVJIoDRt9@pKoQmPSDj74s/3ptxvDyZpq6naHqRfnz1aAzX1DWK8MsfRty1fVmtl3lMhXnrLGFyVfsw2ftHGXMMAOWLZgePSX9qg85lDxPIFWBSWD/lYRvcxI9D9iHORJiRDh6x9orVNehLRd1/NEWjfKx9VH5fN/yvp@@pum5BnPOushxo0Fc@omWzivTSDLoiiW9N4hPn1ZbQjuEXQHV1D9oAA/EJLhmu47Eg3x/TyZWMkppdMN)

The easiest way to group `detective` with `alwayscooperate` and `alwayscheat` was based on text length, while the easiest to group `detective` with `copycat` and `grudger` was alphabetically.

This might internally generate a list that is too long, but that gets trimmed down in the end.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>42</s>  41 bytes

Expects `(strategy)(rounds)`. Returns a string of 0's and 1's.

```javascript
(s,i=14)=>g=b=>--b&&[s>g&!s[++i>>1]]+g(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ndLfaoMwFAbw@z1F5oVT1BVXtyLUPIL3Il7EePwzxEgSHT69izW2tKO07FwG8uP7DuebjERQ3vTS61gBcxnNlnCbyA/sCFdRHmHPy00zFbgyX0XqOA3GfpY5lZXbM2WdYC28t6yySsuo@FBUwA3b2ts2Os9uh5IkNhDjKD1@IMkHWU9oJO0AAruoJK2AKXu5wQqQQGUzguI@L5zCjDiOz95e/9eei7V/1yXtD5kErYFIJR82WbvLaPlwLeN7EmM9cCKXnGGoOCUdm04AlygMUfwmUA0c8IqqlwcqZf1Er7Nt@ZLTbPm@/rPJ4M8mFWcFS0x7ZYMna@sFhqfOKxfqvrrpw6qXe/Fvq@qSutH8Cw)

#### Commented

```javascript
(                // main function taking:
  s,             //   s = strategy string
  i = 14         //   i = internal counter
) =>             //
g = b =>         // g is a recursive function taking b = number of rounds
  --b &&         //   decrement b; if b = 0, stop and return a final 0
  [              //   singleton array:
    s > g &      //     yield 1 if the strategy is not 'always[something]'
                 //     (i.e. it's greater than 'b...')
    !s[++i >> 1] //     and the character in s at floor(++i / 2) is not
                 //     defined, which is:
                 //       - always true for 'copycat' and 'grudger'
                 //       - true only after 3 turns for 'detective'
  ]              //   end of array, implicitly coerced to a string
  + g(b)         //   append the result of a recursive call
```

This is based on [OP's original answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/235547/2) (now deleted).

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11, <s>76</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```java
s->n->(1-s[6]%2+"").repeat(n>3?3:n-1)+(s[0]/98+"").repeat(n>4?n-4:0)+0
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@Arnauld*
-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*

Input as a character-array and integer, output as a String of 1s/0s.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZFNb8IwDIbv/Aqr0qREbbN2sI/CVjRNmrTDThyrHrI0QFhJq8Rlqqb99i5AJWBinBL5sf2@tld8w8NV8dmJklsL71zp7wGARY5KwMpR1qAq2bzRAlWl2Wv/eRRLbrI8uJjzplEupAlghkbpRZrCHJ46G6Y6TEkc2uwuv7rxPY8yI2vJkeh0OB2OdRhTn9gsyq@Th1M8mupwNI6oH3WTgTNaNx@lM9r73VSqgLWbgewFsxw43c4DgNIi8RamKZwhL4AhnRzFC4nSWd5IR25PCC@/eGvF0sk7dn@OVVUtDcdtbZKcJIiqbsWZwmO50QW55E@/g/34335xtEM/g8MZd2vZZe7XAjYApRF0v5tZa1GuWdUgqx3HUhPre@D52vfG7pkzXtdlSyzD6sWd/dkY3hJK@7CmveJP9ws)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->n->                          // Method with character-array and integer parameters
                                // and String return
                                //  Return the following String:
  (1-                           //   Subtract 1 by:
     s[6]                       //    The 7th unicode value of the input-array
         %2                     //    Modulo-2
           +"")                 //   Convert that 0 or 1 to a String
               .repeat(n>3?     //   If `n` is larger than 3:
                           3    //    Repeat it 3 times
                          :     //   Else:
                           n-1) //    Repeat it `n-1` times instead
  +                             //   Concat:
   (s[0]                        //    The 1st unicode value of the input-array
        /98                     //    Integer-divided by 98
           +"")                 //    Convert that 0 or 1 to a String
                .repeat(n>4?    //    If `n` is larger than 4:
                            n-4 //     Repeat it `n-4` times
                           :    //    Else:
                            0)  //     Don't repeat it at all
  +0                            //   And concat an additional trailing "0"
```

| String |  | `s[6]` | `s[6]%2` | `1-s[6]%2` |  | `s[0]` | `s[0]/98` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| detective |  | 105 (`i`) | 1 | 0 |  | 100 (`d`) | 1 |
| grudger |  | 114 (`r`) | 0 | 1 |  | 103 (`g`) | 1 |
| copycat |  | 116 (`t`) | 0 | 1 |  | 99 (`c`) | 1 |
| alwayscheat |  | 99 (`c`) | 1 | 0 |  | 97 (`a`) | 0 |
| alwayscooperate |  | 99 (`c`) | 1 | 0 |  | 97 (`a`) | 0 |

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZHfa8IwEMff/SuOgpDQNthVN9StMgaDPezJx9KHLI1aV5OSXB1l@Ld3UQv@wPmUcJ@7@37vbs23PFzn360oubXwyQv12wOwyLEQsHaU1ViUbFErgYVW7L37PIsVN2kW3M35UCiX0gQwR1OoZZLAAl5aGyYqTEgU2vQx6z/4nkeZkZXkSFQSz@KJCiPqE5tGWX/Ujy/5cKbC4WRA/UE77TmnVf1VOqed4a0ucti4IchRMc2A0/1AACgtEm9p6tw58gKI6fQsnkuUzvNWOjK6ILz84Y0VKyfv2NMtpnUlDcd97Xh8kSB01Ygbhedywzty46t@J/vRv/2iwQHteqc7HtZyyDyuBWwAhUJQ3W7mjUW5YbpGVjmOpSLW98Dzle9N3LNgvKrKhliG@s3d/dUY3hBKu7CineKu/QM)

Comment: I think `s[0]/98` works instead of `s[1]%5%3`.